Sequential sending of requests from different users using Locust
I have a question about sequential sending of requests. I have an approximate version of the code that I use. I want each subsequent request to come from a new user. My generator simulates the number of requests per minute. If my generator "created" 3 requests - I want to send these requests one after another sequentially using a 'sleep_time', etc.
I am interested in the following questions:

How can I manage the number of users? - An user sent a request -> a new user was spawned -> a new user sent a request
When I create several users at once - they all send a request at the same time and only then the sleep_time is triggered. This does not suit me :(
Is it possible to somehow manage one user? - When you sent a request -> spawned a new user to send the next request -> the old user was "killed/stopped", etc.

def requests_generator():
    """
    Generator function to yield N-request counts dynamically.
    """

    while True:
        requests = random.randint(5, 50)
        sleep_time = round(60 / requests, 2)
        yield requests, sleep_time


class CustomUserTaskSet(TaskSet):
    requests_gen = requests_generator()

    @task
    def first_task(self):
        group = Group()
        requests_count, sleep_time = next(self.requests_gen)

        for _ in range(requests_count):
            group.spawn(self.apply3d)
            gevent.sleep(sleep_time)

    def apply3d(self):
        response = self.client.post("/ENDPOINT", headers=headers)
        logging.info(response.status_code)


class CustomUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [CustomUserTaskSet]


